# New class does not show in reference object browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I added a new class to my Class Library `Domain` called `SongPlayDaily.cs` but for some reason it does not display in my reference object browser. See image and correlated numbers:

1. Observe that the new class exists in my `Domain` class library
2. See that I reference this Class Library in my `Unearth` project.
3. Upon double clicking the `Domain` in the `references` dropdown below `Unearth` the object browser opens and you can see that `SongPlayDaily` is not referenced here
4. This is the console error I experience.

Right clicking on the `SongPlayDaily.cs` in the Class Library I can confirm that the `Build Action: Compile`

What other things can I check to see why this new class may not be showing up?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. I could not reference the new class in another source file. Fixed with your solution. Unbelievably confusing.

Answer (score 4):

So dumb, I switched my `Domain` Class Library framework from 4.6.1 to 4.0 back to 4.6.1, rebuilt my solution and it is now referenced....