# Can't access public class from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a very weird scenario which I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I have a web service which is written in C# and the target framework is 3.5. I have many Classes and Methods but for simplicity I will make use of only two classes in the question.

```
public class PathNames
{
   private string _pathA = "Some Path";
   private string _pathB = "Another Path";
   public string BaseDirectoryPath
   {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(_pathA, _pathB); 
        }
   }
}
```

The second class is as follows:

```
public class UserInformation
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   ...//more properties 
}
```

Both of the above classes are in the same `namespace`.

The web service is referenced in a WebForm Application with the target framework being 4.0. Everything seems to be working fine and I can see the `UserInformation` class when I view it in `Object Browser`. However the `PathNames` class does not seem to be visible in the `Object Broswer`.

Both of the source files in question are set to `Compile` in the `File Properties` windows. I have 5 classes similar to that of `UserInformation` and same settings in the `File Properties` window where they are just simple POCO and only have public auto propteries. These all seem to be coming through and I can access them and see them in the `Object Browser`. For some strange reason I cannot `PathNames` class to come through. I have tried to add some new dummy classes and have the same issue as `PathNames` class. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

1. The web service old ASMX
2. Web service client is being created through VS add service reference
3. Using VS 2017 pro - version 15.6.7.
4. After publish if I de-compile the dll then the `PathNames` class is there. So it's clearly in the dll.
5. I have look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225978/cant-use-public-class-in-my-web-service)** but still no luck.

Comment: Is this a WCF webservice?  Or WebAPI?  or old ASMX?  SOAP or REST?  Please specify.  And are you decorating your classes with any attributes like DataContact / DataMember?  Also how are you creating your webservice client?  Is it via Visual Studio's Add Service Reference?  What shows up in the WSDL?

Comment: @Jim should be a ASMX one OP talking about

Comment: have you tried updating your service reference?

Comment: @Rahul I have updated my service reference numerous times and even deleted it and added it back in

Comment: @Jim I have included the info in the question. The class is not decorated with any attributes

Comment: @Izzy: Doublecheck the URL for the service reference. Are you referring to a local webservice, or a remote one (on a server)? I assume your updates haven't been installed to remote servers (ACC/PROD) yet, so if you update your reference from there you won't see them.

Comment: @Igor: `2. Web service client is being created through VS add service reference`

Comment: @Flater I have checked the URL over and over. I have even completely removed the web service reference from the web application and added it back but still the same issue

Comment: Is `PathNames` an input or output to a web service method that has public access? If not then this could explain it as there would be no need  for the consumer (your windows forms app) to use it.

Comment: Have you tried to run the webservice project and use the automatically generated test pages? ([the pages that look like this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MbWEXo1d8Hc/VYZlgdd2l1I/AAAAAAAAB24/0bFl65_Wp9s/s1600/Six.PNG)). Do these pages show you the `PathNames` class or any method/service you've added since then?

Comment: @Flater Yes I can see all the new methods that I have added

Comment: @Igor It's an output which has public access

Comment: I think at this point you will be the only one that can solve this as I think the questions have been exhausted (at least those that I can think of). My only other suggestion is to read logs. See if there are logs generated when adding the service reference or see if you can adjust the logging level to see if anything else stands out. Good luck.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, I will try to solve the issue and once I have managed I will post it as an answer

Comment: @Izzy have you tried renaming the class, could be that it is a reserved name that may be conflicting with the framework?

Comment: @Nkosi I created a dummy class named Foo but still the same issue

Comment: What happens if you add an empty `set` to the property? I am thinking that the only different is that your problem class has readonly property while the others can be modified. probably needed for serialization

Comment: @Nkosi public `set` or private

Comment: it would need to be public

Comment: @Nkosi ok, I’ll have a go and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Did some quick searches and that look like the problem. XML Serialization has no support for non-public or read-only properties.

Comment: from the sounds of what you are saying, are you sure the dll is getting recompiled?  it sounds like it isn't.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes the dll is getting recompiled. Where the service is publish I have deleted everything from that folder just to make sure it's the latest copy that gets placed there

Comment: @Izzy, can you tell us what is the architecture of all the projects? x64?

Comment: Do you think your case may like the below link?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712002/new-class-does-not-show-in-reference-object-browser

Answer (score 4):

> **Using Data Contracts in web service**

**Service can't expose private/read-only properties.** DataMember attribute is used for marking public members or properties (with public getter and setter) of class marked with DataContract attribute. DataContract can be used as parameter or return value of operation.

Windows Communication Foundation (**WCF**) **uses a serialization engine called the Data Contract Serializer** by default to serialize and deserialize data (convert it to and from XML), and **XML serialization (by default) doesn't serialize read=only properties**.

For More Information you can read the MS Docs for Data Contracts :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts

To understand the various Limitation of Data Contracts please refer : -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer

> **Solution :**

Anyway. What are you trying to do? Exposing properties means that you expect some stateful behavior. **If you going to use this property in operation contract, which is seems to be, then you you must define the properties with public getter and setter** so it can be serialized.

**As the @[Nikosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) stated in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101221/6061907), you have to define public setter for your BaseDirectoryPath property**.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference based on the example provided that one property is `readonly` while the other can be modified.

In order to make the class serializable consider rafactoring the property

```
public class PathNames {
    private string _pathA = "Some Path";
    private string _pathB = "Another Path";

    public PathNames() {
        BaseDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(_pathA, _pathB);
    }

    public string BaseDirectoryPath { get; set; }
}
```

You can use a default constructor to set the default value of the property

or just have an empty setter on the property

```
public class PathNames {
    private string _pathA = "Some Path";
    private string _pathB = "Another Path";

    public string BaseDirectoryPath { 
        get {
            return Path.Combine(_pathA, _pathB);
        }
        set {
            //No OP
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it still seems to be giving me the exact same problem. I have created a whole new class with just one prop with a `get` and `set` but I still can't view it in the object browser or access it

Answer (score 1):

You can see how [creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms464040(v=office.14).aspx).
Might you need to rebuild web service ASP.Net and add your assembly to the global assembly cache (GAC).

I hope this help you.